# Question about creating GUIS "dynamically" on Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, mobile-phones, smartphone

I'm trying to make an android app (I'm new in the Android programming world), and I'm having problems creating the GUI.

The point is that I get information of some data that is divided in days... The problem is that I don't know, until I retrieve the information, how many days the GUI should display.

http://img574.imageshack.us/img574/3787/mainscreen.jpg

The grey part will be a TextView, and, also, the black part will be another TextView with multiple lines.

So, the point is, how can I do to have multiple TextView's without knowing before the exact number? I suppose that I can't declare them in the layout.xml

The only solution that I've been thinking about is to create in the layout 7 pairs of TextView and, when I know the exact number, just use what I have to, and don't use the others... (It's a bad solution)

What do you suggest?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a ListView, which inflates TextView for the items you have.

You can use [this example](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) of how to create sectioned ListView, which will look exactly like you want.

Comment: Thank you! I was reading this and just noticed that I use a very inelegant way (I was creating everything and hiding the header when needed ("gone" visibility)). But your solution seems much much better, albeit more complex of course. I will use that class on my application (hmm, I need to rewrite some of it). It worked fine, but yours seems better. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Android, so other people may offer better, more specific advice.

In the environments I'm familiar with, the problem of displaying an unknown number of items is solved by using not a series of display elements for each data item but a list control. The list component will display as many items as you give it, and can usually be modified to have different appearance for different data, so you're flexible in making it as pretty as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can consider this one also,

- Create a table layout in XML, give it a id: TableLayout table=(TableLayout)findViewById(r.id. ....)
- Create dynamic TextViews using:   TextView day=new TextView(this); day.setText(day name);
- Now add this text view to your table layout : table.addView(day);
- Run the code for textView creation and addition to table in loop

Hope this helps...............